# Key repeating on Tigervnc-server and GDM login Screen Imposible to type paswords

Tags: centos7, vnc, kde-plasma, gdm

Sever  running on a Centos 7 box whit Kde and GDM login Screen the problem it is i ran x0vncserver to access to GDM like this

```
XAUTHORITY=/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-8UsAty6/:0  x0vncserver -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd  -display :0
```

and i can connect to just fine but when i try to type a password to login the keys start to repeating it self many time no matters if just type one fast time the key I have read to change the speed of repeating keys in settings and it work for the rest of the session once I login but not in the GDM Login Screen where I should change that parameter Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did Fix it changing GDM3 to login auto to my user

like this

```
nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf

[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=MyUser
```

Well better then nothing right ?